# The ?. operator in languages besides CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, operators

I've seen the use of `?.` operator in an [article](https://tech.dropbox.com/?p=361) on CoffeeScript:

```
e.dataTransfer?.types?.contains 'Files'
```

which is equivalent to JavaScript's

```
e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.types && e.dataTransfer.types.contains('Files')
```

Is there a name for such operator, and does it exist in other languages?

Comment: CoffeeScript calls it the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators).

Comment: It is closely related to `?:`, the "Elvis operator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is called **"Safe navigation"** operator, it is presented in Groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator

Answer (score 0):

It's called a safe navigation operator.  Ruby has this as of 2.3.0: http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

As mentioned in that article C# and Groovy also have this type of operator.